# How to get value of a parameter named "controller" in zend?

Tags: php, zend-framework

In Zend I am trying to get value for a parameter named "controller" but it returns the name of the controller itself instead of the value of the parameter. 
when I try to access the parameter from within the controller using following code. It gives me the name of the controller instead of the value of the parameter.

```
$this->getParam('controller')//returns controller name
```

Comment: use another name for your parameter ?

Comment: I have done that but I am just curious if there is a way to get "controller" anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$this->getRequest()->getParam('controller');
```